# ExecuteQuery WindowsAzure.Storage 5.0.3 no extension method

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

Currently I am trying to execute a query with windows azure storage 5.0.3 
Only getting the following error: Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line

> Error CS1061  'CloudTable' does not contain a definition for
>   'ExecuteQuery' and no extension method 'ExecuteQuery'

Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Can you indicate which platform you're targeting? The PCL, win8 and DNX targets do not contain an ExecuteQuery method -- are you targeting one of these?